# Excel---Counting duplicate data

Tags: excel, vba

```
APC NM000038
APC NM000038
APC NM000038
APC NM000038
APC NM001127510
APC NM001127510
APC NM001127510
```

I was trying to count duplicate data in excel. I cant find relevant answers, so I just ask here. And thank you for answering in advance.

I am trying to countif - with two columns of information. if the values in
column A = certain criteria, i want to count the number of times a value
appears in Column B (Do not count the same value from column B, only count the different values) - not all values in column A correspond to column b
values. So if I want to see how many females received a "5", I need to see
how many "female" in column A have a corresponding value of "5" in column B.
(not all females have a "5", values can be 1 through 5)

In the above example, I expect

```
NM001127510  2
NM000038     2
```

Comment: In general, a `sum over (multiple value match)` can be done with `SUMIF`. Would you clarify how your data is organized? What is in columns A and B?

Comment: Shouldn't this table be:  `NM001127510  3` and `NM000038     4`?  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you data is in cell A1 to B1000, use this formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A1000="APC")*(B1:B1000="NM000038"))
```

similarly

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A1000="APC")*(B1:B1000="NM001127510"))
```

**FOLLOWUP**

> I did that, but the data sets are huge, several hundred MB excel file. I m not sure whether i need to use vba to do that, cuz i dont know a lot about vba – Maggie Mi 7 hours ago

If you Excel Files are >= 100 mb then opening it and then running the VBA code or using formulas **will take a lot of time**. If you are just concerned with the results then try this :)

Open a new Excel File. Ensure your other file is closed. In a module paste this code. When you run this, the output will be pasted in Sheet1.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim adodb As Object
    Dim result

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set adodb = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    adodb.CursorLocation = 3

    adodb.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & _
                  "C:\book1.xlsx" & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;IMEX=1" & _
                  "HDR=NO;" & """"

    Set result = adodb.Execute("Select F1, F2, Count(*) from [Sheet1$] Group by F1,F2")

    With ws
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(result.RecordCount, result.Fields.Count)) _
        = Application.Transpose(result.GetRows)
    End With

    '~~> Cleanup
    result.Close
    adodb.Close
    Set adodb = Nothing
    Set result = Nothing
End Sub
```

**MY ASSUMPTIONS (Change the above code - My code is based on below assumptions)**

1) You are working with Excel 2007/2010 files. If not, then you will have to change the connection string. Please see this link for an appropriate connection string.

http://connectionstrings.com/excel

2) The name of your Excel file which has the data is called `Book1.xlsx` and the data is in `Sheet1`. Also it resides in `C:\`

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

Comment: But the difficult is, I have several thousand of data sets, each of them may has a different string(NMXXXXXX), I dont know how to count them all

Comment: Then may I suggest a Pivot Table?

Comment: I did that, but the data sets are huge, several hundred MB excel file. I m not sure whether i need to use vba to do that, cuz i dont know a lot about vba